# How do you inherit an eosio contract?

Tags: smart-contract

I am trying to inherit the 'eosio.token' contract found in '/eos/contracts/eosio.token/' into my new class 'my.token'

My CMakeLists.txt looks like

```
file(GLOB ABI_FILES "*.abi")
configure_file("${ABI_FILES}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}" COPYONLY)

add_wast_executable(TARGET my.token
  INCLUDE_FOLDERS "${STANDARD_INCLUDE_FOLDERS}"
  LIBRARIES libc++ libc eosiolib eosio.token
  DESTINATION_FOLDER ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
)
```

my.token.hpp is

```
#include <eosio.token/eosio.token.hpp>

namespace eosio {

class mytoken : public token {

public:

    mytoken( account_name self ) : token( self ) {}

};

}
```

And my.token.cpp is just

```
#include "my.token.hpp"

EOSIO_ABI(eosio::mytoken, (create)(issue)(transfer) )
```

When I compile with

```
$cd ~/eos/build
$make
```

It builds fine.  No problem.  But when I go to deploy the contract with
`cleos set contract mytoken ~/eos/build/contracts/my.token/`

I get the following error in the nodeos console output:

```
2068185ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:405           handle_exception     ] FC Exception encountered while processing chain.push_transaction
2068185ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:406           handle_exception     ] Exception Details: 10 assert_exception: Assert Exception
!"unresolvable": env._ZN5eosio5token6createEyNS_5assetE
    {"module":"env","export":"_ZN5eosio5token6createEyNS_5assetE"}
    thread-0  wasm_interface.hpp:41 resolve

    {"mod_name":"env","export_name":"_ZN5eosio5token6createEyNS_5assetE"}
    thread-0  wasm_interface.hpp:43 resolve

    {"_pending_console_output.str()":""}
    thread-0  apply_context.cpp:62 exec_one
```

Does anyone know how to do this, or is it not supported yet?

Answer (score 1):

Because now the EOS only support to build one cpp file, so you can include the `eosio.token.cpp` in your cpp file.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the help.  Now I am getting the error
`error: redefinition of 'apply' EOSIO_ABI(eosio::my.token, (create)(issue)(transfer) )`

Comment: you don't need to  define, because the parent is already do  that

Answer (score 1):

the only way it worked for me is when I first redefined EOSIO_ABI macro to dummy , then included `eosio.token/eosio.token.cpp` , then redefined it back to what it was so I could use it in `mytoken.cpp`

```
#undef EOSIO_ABI
#define EOSIO_ABI( TYPE, MEMBERS )

#include <eosio.token/eosio.token.cpp>

#undef EOSIO_ABI
#define EOSIO_ABI( TYPE, MEMBERS ) \
extern "C" { \
   void apply( uint64_t receiver, uint64_t code, uint64_t action ) { \
      auto self = receiver; \
      if( action == N(onerror)) { \
         /* onerror is only valid if it is for the "eosio" code account and authorized by "eosio"'s "active permission */ \
         eosio_assert(code == N(eosio), "onerror action's are only valid from the \"eosio\" system account"); \
      } \
      if( code == self || action == N(onerror) ) { \
         TYPE thiscontract( self ); \
         switch( action ) { \
            EOSIO_API( TYPE, MEMBERS ) \
         } \
         /* does not allow destructor of thiscontract to run: eosio_exit(0); */ \
      } \
   } \
} \
```

Also , if you are using same function names in your derived class as in `eosio.token` you will get this error from ABI generator

`find_struct(method_name) == nullptr: action already exists issue`

if the reason for subclassing is to add logic to your token say you want to add some additional logic to action  `issue()` that will augment standard logic I would suggest rename it to `issuexyz()` and then do

`EOSIO_ABI( mytoken::token, (create)(issuexyz)(transfer)`

Your code would look like that

```
#include <eosiolib/dispatcher.hpp>

#undef EOSIO_ABI
#define EOSIO_ABI( TYPE, MEMBERS )

#include <eosio.token/eosio.token.cpp>

#undef EOSIO_ABI
#define EOSIO_ABI( TYPE, MEMBERS ) \
extern "C" { \
void apply( uint64_t receiver, uint64_t code, uint64_t action ) { \
      auto self = receiver; \
      if( action == N(onerror)) { \
         /* onerror is only valid if it is for the "eosio" code account and authorized by "eosio"'s "active permission */ \
         eosio_assert(code == N(eosio), "onerror action's are only valid from the \"eosio\" system account"); \
      } \
      if( code == self || action == N(onerror) ) { \
         TYPE thiscontract( self ); \
         switch( action ) { \
            EOSIO_API( TYPE, MEMBERS ) \
         } \
         /* does not allow destructor of thiscontract to run: eosio_exit(0); */ \
      } \
   } \
} \

namespace mytoken {

using namespace eosio;

class mytoken : public token {
   using base = token;

public:

    mytoken( account_name self ) : base( self ) {}
    void issuexyz(account_name to, const asset &quantity, const std::string &memo, bool myflag) {

        if(myflag) {
           //custom logic goes here say you want to add additional checks
        }
        base::issue(to, quantity, memo);
    } 

};

}

EOSIO_ABI( mytoken::mytoken, (create)(issuexyz)(transfer))
```

Comment: But how can i access the table  they are not generated in my .abi file??

Answer (score 0):

At the time of my answer, the [issue #43](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/issues/43) is still open. I guess they had/have other plans for the issue.

And I guess that is connected to ABI generation.
I have tried to inherit my contract from eosio::token and don't see `token`'s tables in *.abi file.